# Divide Two Numbers In PHP

Tags: php

A dev wrote a function to get the average of two numbers in php.  This is how it is set-up

```
$extract_avg1 = getAvgByType($mydata2, ['field2', 'field1']);
foreach ($extract_avg1 as $val) {
    $tr_html .= "<td>$val</td>";
}
```

And the function `getAvgByType()` is set-up like this

```
function getAvgByType($arr, $arr_type)
{
    $arr_avg = array();
    $arr_header = array();
    foreach ($arr as $adata) {
        $type = $adata["type"];
        if (in_array($type, $arr_type)) {
            foreach ($adata as $key => $val) {
                if ($key != 'type') {
                    $prev = 0;
                    if (!empty($arr_avg[$key])) {
                        $prev = $arr_avg[$key];
                    }

                    $arr_avg[$key] = $prev + intval($val);
                    $arr_header[$key] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($arr_header as $key => $val) {
        $arr_avg[$key] = $arr_avg[$key] / count($arr_type);
    }

    return $arr_avg;
}
```

Now we face an issue of no longer needing to capture the `AVG()` but simply dividing two numbers.  How can we -rewrite this function so that it simply performs the calculation of

```
field2/field1
```

**EDIT**
`field1` and `field2` are both of datatype `int` and example values that I am wanting to divide would be like `93489/262872` and the output I'd expect would be `.36`

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can't divide two strings.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - then I would need a way to ``cast()`` or ``convert()`` them as ``int`` then divide them.

Comment: Is `['field2', 'field1']` meant to be numbers? Casting either of those as an int currently would be equal to `0`

Comment: Casting is done via `(integer)$variable`, but strings don't cast to ints cleanly (`(integer)'string'` is `0`)

Comment: I am pulling the data from a MySQL database.  In the database it has a type of ``INT(11)``, so it should retain that type in the php, correct?  In the php code, I'm going from ``object`` to ``array`` which if memory serves, should retain the dataype of ``INT``

Comment: Yes it should. Please update your question with more accurate data that would be used in the function.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I edit question to show sample data and expected output

Comment: Does `$mydata2` contain the actual values? And `$arr_type` just tells you which type it is?

Comment: Edit the question and show sample contents of `$mdata2` and the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

> `field1` and `field2` are both of datatype `int` and example values that I
> am wanting to divide would be like `93489`/`262872` and the output I'd
> expect would be `.36`

```
function getAvgByType($arr, $arr_type) {

    //array keys start at 0
    $field1 = $arr_type[0];
    $field2 = $arr_type[1];
    
    //divide and round up to 2 decimal points
    return round($field2 / $field1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Something must be converting my numbers, bc if I ``echo round($field2/$field1, 2)`` what displays on screen is ``NAN``

Comment: @jamesMandatory Then `$field1` and `$field2` are not what you claim they are.

Comment: Assuming this function isn't used all over the place: I'd seriously just get rid of it altogether, and simply use `round($field2 / $field1, 2);` inline. Operations this basic don't really call for functions, do they... We wouldn't do `function sum_number_pair(a, $b) { return $a + $b; }` right?!

Comment: @MarkusAO I agree, but was trying to answer OPs question directly.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton right, and it does sound like OP needs a drop-in replacement for this function (and hopefully this function isn't called from other locations that expect the old result). Dev, the author of function, is presumably no longer in business with OP and N/A for refactoring the creations.